# SVN Trunk-Tag-Comparison and checkout newer files/folders ONLY

Tags: svn, svn-checkout

Is it possible only to get files or folders from trunk that are newer (revision no.) than
the last tag version, via svn commandline client?

I would like to checkout all files in actual trunk that are new or touched since the last tag-copy in a separate folder. Not for working on this files, but for delivering the changed projectfolders and files only...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Got it by myself:

Use SVN console client to do c:>svn diff   --summarize --xml

Write the response in a XML-file and parse it with NANT ("")

If XML has no "path" nodes old and new path are equal.
Otherwise new path has been changed.